# React - Ant Design change default filter icon in table to material icon

Tags: reactjs, icons, antd

I want to change the default filter icon in Ant Design table to material filter icon. There is no parameter to specify the icon in table also the behaviour when the icon is active.Please see the two screenshots with current icon and desired output I think it is to do with changing the default filter icon of ant design to material filter icon.

[This is how the filter icon is at present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij56H.png)

[This is the desired icon I want to change to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2AFI.png)

Please let me know how this could be changed ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update (`antd` v4)

Use [`filterIcon`](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column) column prop.

- [Official example](https://codesandbox.io/s/901is)

```
filterIcon: filtered => <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />
```

---

You can't, you need to implement your own filter as shown in the docs.

[`Table.Column`](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column) - `filterDropdown` prop accepts a React component so you can render whatever you like.

- [Official example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tqsrp)
- [Table Docs](https://ant.design/components/table/)

Answer (score 0):

`filterIcon` is what you looking for

You can see an example in the docs:

[Docs](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-custom-filter-panel)

```
{
   ...
   filterIcon: filtered => <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />
   ...
}
```